# Unable to export Intellij project to local Git directory

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use Intellij Community Edition and want to share my new non-VCS based project to existing Git repository directory.
Under Eclipse, I can export a non-VCS-project to Git and specify the local git repository, based on a given directory, e.g,
Eclipse-project under C:\, but Git repository under D:\ without use of any webserver or other stuff. 
Using Intellij, I can select only "Enable VCS => Git" and it will create a git repo under current project structure, which is a little bit annoying in case of daily and weekly backups.

Do I miss something or doesn't support Intellij such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

What Eclipse does when you share your project and select a location that is different from the current project path, is moving your project files from the workspace folder to the selected folder, and creates a git repository in that folder.

In IntelliJ, there is no such concept as workspace, the top unit is project, and it expects that you create project in the place you want it to be, so the action just creates a repo in the project root. There is no action that will copy the project somewhere and and create a repo in the new location, as it is not needed for the concepts IntelliJ uses.